# Trouble with generics, comparators, to sort Map

Tags: java, generics, comparator

The original purpose is to retrieve a sorted-by-value list of items in a HashMap.

The rough code (names just simplified):

```
public abstract class Thing<T> implements Iface<T> {
    private HashMap<T, Integer> map;

    static class DescendingValueComparator<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K,V> a, Map.Entry<K,V> b) {
            return (b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue()));
        }
    }

    public LinkedHashMap<T, Integer> getSorted() {
        LinkedHashMap<T, Integer> linked = new LinkedHashMap<T, Integer>();
        ArrayList<Map.Entry<T, Integer>> s = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<T, Integer>>(map.entrySet());

        Arrays.sort(s, new DescendingValueComparator<T, Integer>());
        //...
        }
}
```

The compiler error:

```
Thing.java:30: error: no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList<Entry<T#1,Integer>>,DescendingValueComparator<T#1,Integer>)
        Arrays.sort(sorted, new DescendingValueComparator<T, Integer>());
              ^
    method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.<T#3>sort(T#3[],Comparator<? super T#3>) is not applicable
      (no instance(s) of type variable(s) T#3 exist so that argument type ArrayList<Entry<T#1,Integer>> conforms to formal parameter type T#3[])
    method Arrays.sort(Object[],int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(Object[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(double[],int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(double[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(float[],int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(float[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(byte[],int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(byte[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(char[],int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(char[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(short[],int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(short[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(long[],int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(long[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(int[],int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Arrays.sort(int[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where T#1,T#2,T#3 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in class Thing
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>)
    T#3 extends Object declared in method <T#3>sort(T#3[],Comparator<? super T#3>)
1 error
```

I can generally understand basic generics, but I'm getting thrown off a bit by things like T#x, for example. I've blindly tried changing a few things that seem off, like instead making a

```
new DescendingValueComparator<Map.Entry<T, Integer>>()
```

but I've been staring at this for so long that nothing makes sense anymore. 
(If anyone has a good comprehensive reference on generics, I'd appreciate a link to it).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Arrays.sort` on an `ArrayList`.

`Arrays.sort` takes an array.

You should use `Collections.sort` instead.